# How to setup Load Balancing on DAS (Dell MD3220)

Tags: load-balancing, storage, direct-attached-storage, hba

We have a Dell MD3220 attached through two 6Gb/s HBA controllers.  We want to enable Load Balancing to improve performance.  What at the requirements and steps?

Comment: What is the host OS?

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 - [Read the manual](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pvaul/en/powervault-md3200-md3220-technical-guidebook-en.pdf)

Step 2 - Install and configure the failover driver, per the manual. This driver allows you to control path selection. What you're looking for is active/active multi-path.

Comment: can you do that with an RDAC device?

Comment: Can you READ THE MANUAL?